# How can I set alpha from a drawable selector in API 23+?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-selector

I want to set a Bitmap as an ImageButton's src, and have it become partially transparent while pressed. However, the `android:alpha` attribute in the selector doesn't seem to *do anything*.

I've defined a [StateListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) using my `@drawable/all_close`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/all_close" android:alpha="0.5" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/all_close" android:alpha="1.0" />
</selector>
<!-- have also tried alpha as 0 to 255, with the same result -->
```

I've set that drawable as my ImageButton's src:

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/all_nav_close"
    android:background="@drawable/none"/>
<!-- some attributes omitted for space -->
```

When pressed, the button doesn't change. The selector is definitely being used, as changing the `state_pressed` drawable will visibly change the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/all_add" android:alpha="0.5" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/all_close" android:alpha="1.0" />
</selector>
```

However, the `android:alpha` attribute doesn't seem to have any effect on opacity. The project builds and installs. The attribute doesn't trigger the "Unknown attribute" linter warning (and build failure), but it's not suggested by the IDE.

This is on API 23, using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0` and `com.android.support:design:25.0.0`.

Comment: The image is a white png on a transparent background, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do you try with code? I use this in my apps.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAlpha(100);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint);
```

But... check what you need and change depends what you need, Imageview,Paint or Bitmap:

```
ImageView.setAlpha().
BitmapDrawable.setAlpha().
```

Comment: I just did, and using .setAlpha(0.5f) does grey out the button - thanks for the idea! So using alpha does what I want; it's just the xml that doesn't set alpha properly(?) I'd rather not use code because this pattern is going to be used in multiple places, and I'd rather use Android styles than extending ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

hi i have done this using this way please check, 
When you enter the screen see how it work

```
 @Override
public void centerScene(ImageView sharedElement) {
    binding.sharedImage.setTranslationY(0);
    setSharedImageRadius(binding.sharedImage, 0);

    binding.deviceImage.setAlpha(1.0f);
    binding.deviceText.setAlpha(1.0f);
    binding.deviceImage.setAlpha(1.0f);
    binding.deviceImage.setScaleX(1.0f);
}
```

when  you exit the screen

```
 //position goes from -1.0 to 0.0
 @Override
 public void exitScene(ImageView sharedElement, float position) {
    binding.sharedImage.setTranslationY(
            getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tutorial_shared_element_translate_y)
                    * position);

    setSharedImageRadius(binding.sharedImage, -position);

    binding.deviceText.setAlpha(1 + position);
    binding.deviceImage.setAlpha(1 + position);
    binding.deviceImage.setScaleX(1 - position); // stretch
}

@Override
public void notInScene() {
    binding.deviceImage.setAlpha(0.0f);
    binding.deviceText.setAlpha(0.0f);
}
```

If you don't want to use binding replace it with butter knife.

Checkout this [example](https://github.com/eoinfogarty/Onboarding) for more information.You can understand all things.

Comment: That demonstrates setting alpha through code, thanks. I'm especially interested in setting alpha through XML - the Onboarding project doesn't seem to do this? Data binding is nice though.